# Delete folders from the SD storage

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, internal-sd, folder-organizer

I have a Nexus 4 smartphone and in external storage there are many folders which I believe to be unused and/or empty.

Is it possible to delete them safely? In other words, if I delete an empty folder that is really needed by an app, will it get recreated automatically or will I break the app?

Answer (score 1):

If they are empty, they can be deleted. They will be recreated as needed. Before deleting them, make sure that they really are empty. As in, not even hidden files are there, except for ones like ".nomedia"

Answer (score 1):

Removing empty folders may not account for much space, but the following will help you remove them.

Install "SD Maid" from the Playstore then run 'SystemCleaner' from within.

To remove junk files install "Clean Master" then click on  'Junk Files', cache files  and APK files may use up a significant amount of space.   Faster here than clearing cache files for each application and it is not just browsers that have old cache files.